# NHibernate Fluent C# Mapping Isuses

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I create my table like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
EmailAddress varchar(255),
FullName varchar(255),
Password varchar(255),
);
```

My model is:

```
public class UserModel : Entity
{
    public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
}
```

My entity class is:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping class is simple as below:

```
public class UserModelMap : ClassMap<UserModel>
{
    public UserModelMap()
    {
        Table("Users");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.EmailAddress);
        Map(x => x.FullName);
        Map(x => x.Password);
    }
}
```

And i include all my classes the have to be mapped using this following configuraiton:

```
        private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
             .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("DefalutConnection"))
            )
            .Mappings(m =>
                      m.FluentMappings
                          .AddFromAssemblyOf<Entity>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                            .Create(true, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

But when i query my database using the following code:

```
Session.Query<TEntity>();
```

Where TEntityis my user model i get no rows back from the database.

I cant seem to work out what the issue is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, that the problem is here:

```
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg 
   => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true)) // here
```

Because, as NHibernate says: everything is OK, **no** issue, no exception. Just **NO** data. And you are recreating schema all the time, I would say.

Check this:

- [Fluent NHibernate automatically deletes data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179360/)
- [Fluent NHibernate - always drop table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566728/)

An extract from one of the answers:

> You could use SchemaUpdate, which will update the schema instead. Here's a blog post about it: http://geekswithblogs.net/dotnetnomad/archive/2010/02/22/138094.aspx